# ostream: prefix a positive number with a space

Tags: c++

In C a space can be included in a printf formatting flag which results in positive numbers being prefixed with a space.  This is a useful feature for aligning signed values.  I can't figure out how to do the same in C++.  In C:

```
double d = 1.2;
printf("%f\n",d);
printf("%+f\n",d);
printf("% f\n",d);
```

produces:

```
1.2
+1.2
 1.2
```

Using ostream, I can do the first two, but how do I do the third?

```
int d = 1.2;
std::cout << d << std::endl;
std::cout << std::showpos << d << std::endl;
// ??????????????
```

EDIT:  There seems to be some confusion about whether or not I just want to prefix all of my values with a space.  I only want to prefix *positive* values with a space, similar to a) like the printf space flag does and b) similar to what showpos does, except a space rather than a '+'.  For example:

```
printf("%f\n", 1.2);
printf("%f\n", -1.2);
printf("% f\n", 1.2);
printf("% f\n", -1.2);

1.2
-1.2
 1.2
-1.2
```

Note that the third value is prefixed with a space while the fourth (negative) value is not.

Comment: Are you just trying to print a space?

std::cout << " ";

Comment: If you need numbers to be aligned, usually you need to use fixed precision and   a certain field width.  If you do that, then you'll also get the extra space at the beginning as needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `setfill` and `setw`, like this:

```
cout << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << 1.2 << endl;
cout << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << -1.2 << endl;
```

This produces the following output:

```
 1.2
-1.2
```

Don't forget to include `<iomanip>` in order for this to compile ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/pCQ0M)).

Comment: That only works if both numbers have the same precision.  If the values are 1.2 and -1.0, it won't work.

Comment: You can use `std::showpoint` to force `-1.0` to print as `-1.0` instead of `-1`.

Comment: And if the values were 1.22 and -1.2?

Comment: @J.Kraftcheck How would you like the `1.22` and `-1.2` displayed?

Comment: Then you can use `std::setprecision` to set the floating precision. This would show as `1.22` and `-1.20` with a precision of 3.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have my standard with me and I'm doing this stuff too rarely to be confident about it: There are two ingredients to achieving this with IOStreams:

1. Use `std:: showpos` to have an indicator of positive values be shown. By default this will use `+`, of course.
2. I *think* the `+` is obtained using `std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(s.get_loc()).widen('+')`. To turn this into a space you could just use a `std::locale` with a `std::ctype<char>` facet installed responding with a space to the request to *widen* `+`.

That is, something like this:

```
struct my_ctype: std::ctype<char> {
    char do_widen(char c) const {
        return c == '+'? ' ': this->std::ctype<char>::do_widen(c);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new my_ctype);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << std::showpos << 12.34 << '\n';
}
```

(the code isn't tested and probably riddled with errors).

Comment: This doesn't do the job. do_widen gets called but that's it. Plus sign is always shown regardless of what do_widen returns. Plus sign is not shown when std::showpos is omited; regardless of what do_widen returns.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
std::cout << (d >= 0 ? " ":"")  << d << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << " " << my_value;
```

If you need space only for positive:

```
if (my_value >=0 ) cout << " "; cout << my_value;
```

Comment: That won't do the correct thing if `my_value` is negative.  I only want a space if the value is positive, such that negative and positive values align (similar to what std::Showpos does, except a space instead of a '+').